# Transrate RedHawk StartUp Python program to C++ Program

Tags: redhawksdr

I previously asked for "About writing C ++ RedHawk startup program", but even if I read the CORBA specifications, I could not establish a method to launch the application from waveform and RedHawk's domain search. I think that by rewriting the Python program packaged in RedHawk into C ++, I can create a C ++ startup program. Is the way of thinking fit?
Even though I deleted Python and made image size compact, I can not make sense unless I can start with my own CPU.I would like to teach even just direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yoshida.. you have been persistent, but you need to dig the core-framework source code in order to learn how to do what you want. Looking at the methot linked [here](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/core-framework/blob/a291ec1996606104115dbe2c7a20e31bc9a58f73/redhawk/src/control/sdr/devmgr/DeviceManager_impl.cpp#L1212)

```
void DeviceManager_impl::getDomainManagerReference (const std::string& domainManagerName)
```

try to find a way to get the reference of the domain [by its name](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/core-framework/blob/4713ef8b38b2ca129053df1a2f7941a30e8d50eb/redhawk/src/base/framework/CorbaUtils.cpp#L237). Then you will have the Domain methods available in order to start applications. Having the `CORBA::Object_ptr` of the Domain/Device/Resource you are able to get its reference using `_narrow()` method. For the Domain you'll get access to methods like:

```
createApplication
installApplication
uninstallApplication
deviceManagers
applications
```

that should be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I think that I need to dig the core-framework source code... However, each Domain/Device/Resource/Application class have stub code in ossie/CF/cf.h. Using to object reference call in ossie/CF/cf.h. This method is correct? Can I do it without digging in core-framework source code?

Comment: When I tell you to 'dig' I mean that you might learn a lot studying the core-framework implementation. I didn't understand your question. There are classes definitions in this header file. But how do you plan to get the reference of the domain that was launched by [nodeBooter](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/core-framework/blob/a291ec1996606104115dbe2c7a20e31bc9a58f73/redhawk/src/control/framework/nodebooter.cpp)?

Comment: You are Right. I'm thinking that how to get the reference of the domain that was launched by nodeBooter. In this case, the class in the header file can not be used...It is difficult for me to understand core-framework source code. Well I'll do my best.